# Extract data from Collection class

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, class, object

I have an API call that returns a JSON response:
JSON response:

```
{
    "Errors":
    [
        {"Message":"The username supplied is invalid or already in use. Please choose a different username."}
    ]
}
```

My Classes:

```
public class Error
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorCollector
{
    public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is extract the message only from this JSON Response but when I try to extract the data I get no option of `Message`, here is my code to collect data from JSON Response.

```
var thisasa3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSonClasses.ErrorCollect>(response.Content);
string Responsess = thisasa3.Errors. //<< No opntion for Message
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried to change the List to ILIST as well but didn't work.

Comment: Since there are can be many errors (they are put into a JSON array for a reason), which error's message do you want?

Comment: Hi @Sweeper The Error is in the Response right now is the one I want to now only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Errors` is a collection `List<Error> Errors`.  You need to iterate through all errors to get the messages inside. For example:

```
string Responsess = thisasa3.Errors;
var messages = string.Empty;
foreach (var error in Responsess.Errors)
{
    messages += $"{error.Message} ";
}
```

Or simply with [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8):

```
// all messages
string messages = string,Join(", ", thisasa3.Errors);
```

If you only want the first error, or there is only one then:

```
// first message
string message = thisasa3.Errors?[0].Message;
```

Or using `System.Linq`:

```
// first message
string message = thisasa3.Errors.FirstOrDefault()?.Message;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are deserializing a list, and trying to retrieve an object, to get your message you need to get the first item in the list.

Like this:

```
var thisasa3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSonClasses.ErrorCollect>(response.Content);
var response = thisasa3.Errors[0].Message;
```

Comment: Hi @Guilherme Martin I think its supposed to be `var response = thisasa3.Errors[0].Message` Like @haldo mentioned in their answer.